# Find the probability that Bob understands Alice correctly (detail below).

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Alice is trying to transmit to Bob the answer to a yes-no question, using a noisy channel. She encodes “yes” as 1 and “no” as 0, and sends the appropriate value. However, the channel adds noise; specifically, Bob receives what Alice sends plus N(0, σ2). If Bob receives a value greater than 0.5 he interprets it as “yes”; otherwise, he interprets it as “no”.

I know that $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^4}$$
but I don't know where to go from there or how the value .5 plays a role here.

Comment: I know that ....................  Please let us know what that means in relation to the question you are asking.  What is $x$?  As it stands, your questions is *unclear*.

Comment: hint: one way to look at it: You're looking for  the probability that Bob interprets Alice's message as "1" given that she sent a 1, i.e. one minus the probability that the normal RV $\mathcal{N}(1,\sigma ^2 )$ is less than .5